# Virtual Surround Sound software

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones

Is there any similar software in Ubuntu for virtual surround sound like Windows has Dolby Atmos for Headphones or Razer Surround? These apps take whatever the audio source is (5.1 or stereo) and create nice surround effect in headphones with enhanced sound stage etc. Specially Dolby Atmos for Headphones is excellent in movies or games.

Just for clarification, before you start typing:

I don't need to setup surround sound on my audio receiver, i don't need to fix issues with audio channels or setup downmix and i don't need equalizer - PA-E is useless and PulseEfeects is overcomplicated.

Comment: have you looked at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound)

Comment: Yes, that is useless and does not cover what i am looking for.